# Magento Add to Cart slider

Tags: html, magento, slider, cart

Is there a way to replace the add to cart button to a iPhone like slider in Magento?

Also, is there a way to add an external link to the main menu instead of pointing to another category?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a custom template in design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml.

by pasting the  code from base/default/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml, after which you can add the

```
 <div class="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav">
           <?php echo $_menu ?>
           **<li> <a href="external link"> Testimonials </a> </li>**
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Or you can use an extension Flexible Menu (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flexible-menu-9755.html) which may help you to achieve this.

Hope this helps :).

Cheers,
Swapna